# bug with "-> not for ..." in siddhi?

Tags: siddhi

I added the following testcase into AbsentWithEveryPatternTestCase.java, but the test had been failed, which I think should success. So, is there a bug with "-> not for ..." pattern?

```
@Test
public void testQuery7() throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("Test the query every e1 -> not e1 for 1 sec with e1 only");

    SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

    String streams = "@app:playback(idle.time = '10 milliseconds', increment = '10 milliseconds') " +
            "define stream Stream1 (symbol string, price float, volume int); ";
    String query = "" +
            "@info(name = 'query1') " +
            "from every e1=Stream1[price>20] -> not Stream1[symbol==e1.symbol and price>e1.price] for 1sec " +
            "select e1.symbol as symbol " +
            "insert into OutputStream ;";

    SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(streams + query);

    TestUtil.TestCallback callback = TestUtil.addQueryCallback(siddhiAppRuntime, "query1", new Object[]{"GOOG"});

    InputHandler stream1 = siddhiAppRuntime.getInputHandler("Stream1");

    siddhiAppRuntime.start();

    stream1.send(1544512385000L, new Object[]{"WSO2", 55.6f, 100});
    stream1.send(1544512385100L, new Object[]{"GOOG", 55.6f, 100});
    stream1.send(1544512385800L, new Object[]{"WSO2", 55.7f, 100});
    stream1.send(1544512386200L, new Object[]{"GOOG", 55.6f, 100});

    callback.throwAssertionErrors();
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals("Number of success events", 1, callback.getInEventCount());
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals("Number of remove events", 0, callback.getRemoveEventCount());
    AssertJUnit.assertTrue("Event arrived", callback.isEventArrived());

    siddhiAppRuntime.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assertions are failing because you are not allowing time to process events after sending the inputs. How not query works is that for each incoming event it will wait within time to check for occurrence and then emit occurrence after time passes. So you should wait and let pattern query to process. Easiest way is to add a thread sleep after sending.

```
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

Recommended way is to use [waitForEvent utility](https://github.com/tishan89/siddhi/blob/e2099a3432076e7b25cb729ae76c4bd8f652f4bd/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/util/SiddhiTestHelper.java#L30) in Siddhi. [Here](https://github.com/tishan89/siddhi/blob/9bd5a21d75831e899bb46d51b43668c8b917f7b9/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/function/CastFunctionExecutorTestCase.java#L85) is a sample on that.

Also another thing to note is that your query will generate 3 output events as last 3 input events are not followed by another event with higher price.

Comment: Hi Tishan, I understand your suggestion. But, as the 'playback' was used in this query, I think when the last event was sent, the siddhi time should be '1544512386200L', and it is 1 sec over '1544512385100L', which was the time of the second event. So, I suppose 1 output event should be emit at once.

Comment: Even with the playback you will get 3 output events as last 3 events matches your pattern. And also you will have to have the sleep as it takes another one second for the last event to match your condition

Comment: Further looking into this I observed that there is a delay between receiving last event and emitting corresponding occurrence events. We will be looking into this further. Will keep you posted through the github issue that I think you already posted

Comment: Hi Andew, This issue has been addressed with https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/pull/975 Please let us know if your scenario is working as expected now

Comment: Yes, the pull request solved this problem, many thanks for your attention!